# Real player plugin not working with Firefox 5

Tags: firefox, realplayer

I am on Windows 7. I was using firefox 4 with real player plugin for autodownloads from sites like YouTube etc .  The upgrade to Firefox 5 has disabled that feature. Is there any good alternative to that ? I am no big fan of Real Player , I mainly used it to autodetect and offer download of video streams currently being played in the browser window. Any alternative to real player that has this feature will do .

Answer (score 0):

Not a Firefox plugin, but [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) will offer to download YouTube videos in their various available formats.